# Screensharing between Linux and Windows computers

Tags: remote-desktop, screen-sharing, screencasts

I am looking for a way to share the screen from a Linux computer to a Windows PC. Allowing the PC to interact with the Linux computer (i.e. clicking on buttons) is *not* necessary, but it would be fine. I **cannot** use Chrome Remote Desktop. Are there any applications that can do this?

Comment: [Discord](https://discord.com) and [Wire](https://wire.com) can do screen sharing and don't require special installs if you have a modern browser. Just tried Discord and it refused to work with Firefox but it works fine in Chromium in incognito mode. Wire I think works with both Firefox and Chromium.

Answer (score 3):

VNC does exactly this. There's dozens of different VNC servers and clients though:

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=VNC

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for it seems to be a [remote desktop software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_desktop_software).
You can see a [comparison list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software) on wikipedia or on specialized magazines.

Among the others I should **suggest** you [nomachine](https://www.nomachine.com/).

You have to install the server version on the Linux machine (in this case it is the server because it provides the *desktop service*) and the client on Windows (it is from there that you want to use the other machine).

Note that there exists a not payment version and an enterprise one...

Answer (score 1):

What distribution of Linux are you using?

More importantly, what desktop environment?

If you are using Gnome (Ubuntu), you can get pseudo Screen sharing using gnome-session through putty + Xming, and if you are using Cinnamon (Linux Mint) you can use cinnamon-session in the same way.

It's not quite screen sharing, but if your goal is to just use linux through a GUI from a remote PC, this is probably the easiest solution.